# Jsreport default sample mistake

Tags: header, jsreport

I was following the official jsreport guideline. Everything is okay. I run the sample generation of report and the result is great.

But in the sample report, there is no HTML equivalent to "Library Monthly Report" header in the output. Where can I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**
Expand in the left menu the `phantom pdf` submenu, then click on `header > open in tab`

**Explanation**
The header and footer generation is the responsibility of the particular recipe. That is why you find such a setting under the particular recipe submenu. It would not make sense to have such a setting for excel for example.